# set legend in a for loop plot from a cell in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, cell, legend

I need your help to solve a problem i am facing when i am trying to create a legend to a for loop plot. The code i am using is the following

```
for i=3:14
   plot(data(:,i),data(:,2));
   hold all;
end
legend(textdata{1,3:14});
```

texdata is a `1x14 cell` where they are stored the names of the legends i want to use. 
When i am running my script, i get the plot but instead of legend i am getting this error message "??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

edit: i add the `whos textdata` answer, because i can't write it in a good way on comment answer

```
>> whos textdata
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  textdata      1x14             1652  cell
```

Comment: What does `textdata` contain? What does `whos textdata` display?

Comment: whos textdata
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  textdata      1x14             1652  cell

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me using this code. The length of each string in textdata should not matter.

```
data = magic(14);
data(2,:) = 1:10:140;
textdata = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n'};


for i=3:14
   plot(data(:,i),data(:,2));
   hold all;
end
legend(textdata{1,3:14});
```

If the error only comes up on the legend addition you know it is a problem with textdata.. Your plot works fine though I assume?
Are you sure your textdata is stored appropriately? It is likely that textdata is, well, of different dimensions than what you are trying to plot.

Try running whos like the comment says:

```
>> whos textdata
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  textdata      1x14              868  cell
```

edit: comments were updated while I wrote the answer...

Comment: Using your script works fine for me as well. I guess there is something "strange" in texdata cell, actually is the column headers of an imported excel worksheet.

here is `whos` answer

    >> whos textdata
    
          Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
     
          textdata      1x14             1652  cell

Comment: You can list all the members of the list as you want though right? As in, going through and manually adding legend(textdata{1}) works? Perhaps try using legend(textdata(1,3:14)) instead of the brackets...

what exactly is in textdata?